# switch não mostra o resultado esperado

Tags: php, switch

O que está errado? Era pra aparecer "sem valor", mas quando inicia com zero aparece "valor muito alto" na mensagem.

```
<?php
$num = 0;

switch ($num){
    case($num>100);
        echo'valor muito alto';
        break;
    case($num<80 && $num>51);
        echo'valor medio';
        break;
    case($num==50);
        echo'valor perfeito';
        break;
    case($num<=10);
        echo'valor muito baixo';
        break;
    case($num==0);
        echo'sem valor';
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 12):

O `case` não funciona da maneira como você espera. Ele não é um substituto para o `if`. Veja a [documentação dele](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php). O `case` só aceita um valor, ele só testa a igualdade desse valor.

Mais ou menos o que você deseja é isso:

```
$num = 0;
if ($num > 100) echo 'valor muito alto';
else if ($num < 80 && $num > 51) echo 'valor medio';
else if ($num == 50) echo 'valor perfeito';
else if ($num <= 10) echo 'valor muito baixo';
else if ($num == 0) echo'sem valor';
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/E5B2JQ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kexictwl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/Switch2If.php).

Ainda assim tem erro de lógica aí. Sequer dá para entender qual é o objetivo. Tem faixas de valores se sobrepondo, faixas de valores que não são atingidas por nenhum das condições.

Comment: Do jeito que está indo, vai dar a primeira [medalha de reversão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal) do site :)

Answer (score 0):

Testei aqui e deu certo, é uma gambiarra, mas atende a sua necessidade, como quero testar mais de um valor no case, tenho que criar um *array*, como o @Maniero disse, o case não funciona desse jeito ai que tu quer, mas dá pra fazer uma gambiarra.

Criando 3 `arrays` com o intervalo de valores que você quer, e testando se o valor existe dentro do array usando a função `in_array`, fica nice...

```
<?php
    $num = 40;

    $array100_80 = array();
    $array79_51 = array();
    $array49_1 = array();

    for ($i = 80; $i <= 100; $i++) {
        $array100_80[$i] = $i;
    }

    for ($i = 51; $i <= 79; $i++) {
        $array79_51[$i] = $i;
    }

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 49; $i++) {
        $array49_1[$i] = $i;
    }

    switch ($num){
        case(0):
            echo'sem valor';
            break;
        case(in_array($num, $array100_80)):
            echo'valor muito alto';
            break;
        case(in_array($num, $array79_51)):
            echo'valor medio';
            break;
        case(50):
            echo'valor perfeito';
            break;
        case(in_array($num, $array49_1)):
            echo'valor muito baixo';
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Não funciona. Sequer roda. Mesmo que rode não daria certo porque existe três `cases` testando o mesmo valor, `true`.

Comment: eu testei e funcionou kkkkk O.o, detalhe, tentou alterar o valor do $num? Detalhe2, viu que eu alterei a função man?

Comment: Essa última edição melhorou mas não sei se daria certo sempre, não vou perder tempo em testar cada situação, afinal isso é algo tão errado de fazer, é tão sem propósito que não vale o tempo. Mas ainda tem *warning*.

Comment: Que warning velho?
Aqui na empresa que trabalho desabilitamos os Warning's do servidor, não me aparece nenhum erro, como disse, não é o certo a se fazer, é uma gambiarra, mas se não houver opção melhor, é o que tem pra hj né? rs

Comment: Não acho que essa seja uma forma decente de se usar um `Switch/Case`. Aliás em vários materiais de Clean-code pede-se que evite ao máximo o uso. Mas enfim, talvez funcione.

Comment: É `syntax error`. Tem `;` onde deveria ter `:`. Roda mas está errado. Parabéns por desabilitar *warning*.

Comment: kkkkk não sou eu que defino a politica da empresa onde trabalho @bigow, quem dera fosse, mas enfim.....
Dei uma última corrigida pra mor de não dar mais pal ai pra voce

Comment: Ah, e so uma coisa, agora que eu vi,  o meu erro de sintaxe foi devido ao erro de sintaxe do user rs, eu copiei e colei o código dele pra fazer o teste......